# How to make the bar for simplify

Tags: math-mode

[image]

How can i write the bar/slash over the m in latex?

Comment: Try the cancel package: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cancel

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `slashed` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,slashed}
\begin{document}
$P_0(\slashed{m} \frac{t\lambda}{\slashed{m}})$
\end{document}
```

Using Latex to write math equations is easy but overwhelming at the beginning. Maybe you find [Detexify](https://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) or [Mathpix](https://mathpix.com/) useful when you can write down what you need but do not have the words to describe it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Using `\not` command.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}


\begin{document}
\[P_0\left(\not m \frac{\lambda t}{\not m}\right)\]
\end{document}
```

[image]